# Add a pattern of extensions for a MIME type

Tags: iis-7

We are serving static files from a build process where the output files are to be served as application/octet-stream.   The problem is that the files extensions are related to their version, so I need:

.000 application/octet-stream
.001 application/octet-stream
...
.100 application/octet-stram
...

Is there a way in IIS7 to add a pattern of extensions or some other way so I don't have to manually type in 100+ new entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is really no way to specify a regex or pattern for that. I'd suggest scripting it from the command line. See [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28WS.10%29.aspx) for the syntax, but for a single mime type something like this should work:

```
appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+"[fileExtension=' .000 ', mimeType='application/octet-stream ']"
```

So to do it for 100 of them, try this in a windows cmd file:

```
@echo off
FOR /L %%G IN (0,1,100) DO (call :addfile %%G)

:addfile
  if %1 LSS 10 (
     (call :updateconfig 00%1)
  ) else (
    if %1 LSS 100 (
       (call :updateconfig 0%1)
    ) else ( 
       (call :updateconfig %1)
    )
  )
  goto :EOF

:updateconfig
  appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+"[fileExtension=' .%1 ', mimeType='application/octet-stream ']"
  goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add them programatically by reading the extensions from a file or what have you.

A good example of how to do this you cand find [here](http://codesprouts.com/post/Programatically-Add-Mime-Types-In-IIS-70.aspx).